# Want to save another table while saving the table having joinColumn between them

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two classes having link by `joinColumn` and has one-to-one relationship.
I want to set field of one table while setting object of another. Need a help as I am new to it.

Reserve.java

```
class Reserve {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "locker_id", referencedColumnName = "uuid")
    private Locker linkedLocker;

    @Column
    ZonedDateTime startDate;

    @Column
    ZonedDateTime expiryDate;


    public Locker getLinkedLocker() {
        return linkedLocker;
    }

    public void setLinkedLocker(Locker linkedLocker) {
        this.linkedLocker = linkedLocker;
    }
//...

}
```

Locker.java

```
public class Locker extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "is_empty")
    boolean isEmpty = true;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private short number; 

    public void setEmpty(boolean isEmpty) {
        this.isEmpty = isEmpty;
    }

    public byte getSide() {
        return side;
    }
}
```

I am coding a service which need to do that here is the service code:

Service.java

```
@Override
public Boolean freeReserved(String reservationId)  {
    Reserve reservation = reservationRepository.findById(reservationId);
    if (reservation.getLinkedLocker() != null) {
        if (!reservation.getLinkedLocker().isEmpty()) {
            reservation.getLinkedLocker().setEmpty(true);
            reservation.setLinkedLocker(reservation.getLinkedLocker());
            reservationRepository.save(reservation);
        } else {
            log.error(String.format("Invalid reservation"));
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        log.error(String.format("Reservation [%s] is not found", reservationId));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Having above code my locker is not becoming free while setting `isEmpty` to `true`. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can save Locker object using LockerRepository.

For example,

```
reservation.getLinkedLocker.setEmpty(true);
lockerRepository.save(reservation.getLinkedLocker());
```

Second, you can use cascade types above the Locker object field.

```
@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinColumn(name = "locker_id", referencedColumnName = "uuid")
private Locker linkedLocker;
```

Also, you can check this post to understand how cascade types work.
https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/